# WPF and Powershell: Mirroring/Syncing text boxes

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have two text boxes. I would like to mirror the first text box to the second text box, but if you manually update the second box after the text has been mirrored, it  should stay as that regardless of if you update the first text box again.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxUserLogonNameUPN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxUserLogonNameSamAccountName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="326,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=TextBoxUserLogonNameUPN, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I have tried the above but with Mode=OneWay in the Binding. If I update the first text box a second time, after manually updating the second, it wipes what was in the second and mirrors again.

I am using WPF with PowerShell. I am happy to manage this by the Powershell if it can't be done in Xaml.

Comment: This cant be done in XAML alone as you want to have logic. If Textbox 2 changed no more changes via Textbox 1 allowed

Comment: Any ideas on how to implement this using PowerShell?

Comment: can you post your powershell code. Its sounds like this will be a quick solution but i need what you have so far in powershell

Comment: I don't have anything in powershell yet to do this, as was trying to do by Xaml. But I was suspecting that the controls would need to be in the Add_TextChanged event!!

Comment: I have a feeling you'll need to set a variable in the GotFocus event to check if textbox 2 is either blank or equal to textbox 1. Then in the TextChanged event (or the LostFocus event) set the content of textbox 2 dependent on that variable. Or set a flag if the user edits textbox 2 so that textbox 1 no longer updates it.

Comment: @AdamBirds: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @NovaSysEng thanks for the answer below. Didn't need all of it, but the tag statement and if logic did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `textbox1` losing `focus` is the event that should copy `textbox1` text to `textbox2`, this code should work for you. All the action is in the function `textBox1_LostFocus`. The first time through, simply set the `textbox2`[`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.tag#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Tag)property to a value that you test for second and subsequent times through

Note: The form has two labels and two text boxes

WpfWindow1.xaml.ps1 is the entry point for this program

**WpfWindow1.xaml.ps1**

```
function Add-ControlVariables {

New-Variable -Name 'textBox1' -Value $window.FindName('textBox1') -Scope 1 -Force   
New-Variable -Name 'textBox2' -Value $window.FindName('textBox2') -Scope 1 -Force
}

function Load-Xaml {
    [xml]$xaml = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\WpfWindow1.xaml
    $manager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xaml.NameTable
    $manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@x:Name='textBox1']", $manager)[0].RemoveAttribute('TextChanged')
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@x:Name='textBox2']", $manager)[0].RemoveAttribute('TextChanged')
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@x:Name='textBox1']", $manager)[0].RemoveAttribute('LostFocus')
    $xamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
    [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
}

function Set-EventHandlers {

    $textBox1.add_TextChanged({
        param([System.Object]$sender,[System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs]$e)
        textBox1_TextChanged($sender,$e)
    })
    $textBox2.add_TextChanged({
        param([System.Object]$sender,[System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs]$e)
        textBox2_TextChanged($sender,$e)
    })
    $textBox1.add_LostFocus({
        param([System.Object]$sender,[System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e)
        textBox1_LostFocus($sender,$e)
    })
}

$window = Load-Xaml
Add-ControlVariables
Set-EventHandlers

function textBox1_TextChanged
{
    param($sender, $e)
    #do stuff you want to do when textBox1.Text changes
}

function textBox2_TextChanged
{
    param($sender, $e)

    #do stuff you want to do when textBox2.Text changes
}

function textBox1_LostFocus
{
    param($sender, $e)

    if ($textBox2.Tag -ne "mirrored")
    {
        #turn off textBox2 TextChanged event so that code in textBox2_TextChanged is not executed
        $textBox2.remove_TextChanged({
            param([System.Object]$sender,[System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs]$e)
            textBox2_TextChanged($sender,$e)
        })

        $textBox2.Text = $sender.Text
        $textBox2.Tag = "mirrored"

        #turn textBox2 TextChanged event back on
        $textBox2.add_TextChanged({
            param([System.Object]$sender,[System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs]$e)
            textBox2_TextChanged($sender,$e)
        })
    }
}


$window.ShowDialog()
```

**WpfWindow1.xaml**

```
<Window

  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="79,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" LostFocus="textBox1_LostFocus"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="298,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" TextChanged="textBox2_TextChanged"/>
        <Label Content="Text1:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="32,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
        <Label Content="Text2:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="242,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```